# One word looks like two on iPad, but one on Desktop. (That's hard to say)

Tags: ios, css, mobile, responsive-design, media

I have a weird problem. I'm making a homepage responsive, and the  I'm using for the sections headers seems to double itself when viewing on mobile (iOS Simulator)

Here's an image of what happening, because I don't think I can describe it.

[image: Side-By-Side]

And Enhanced...

[image: Enhanced]

Now, I thought maybe it was the multiple declarations I did for @media queries, but after making only one query it still happens. Even after getting rid of all other mentions of .sectionHeader it still happens..

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Here's the @media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .sectionTitle {
        font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
        color: #CEB08B;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 40pt;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em; /* Fixes letter spacing issue on iphone */
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<h1 class="sectionTitle" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Videography</h1><br>
```

Comment: Not sure but might be it happens due to `text-shdow`, you can try `text-shadow:none`

Comment: Thanks for replying - just tried that and it still shows up. I'm chalking it up to Google Fonts. I've tried different ones and it still happens. Only solved with a system font.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to edit this because I (actually) solved it. It was being caused by `font-weight: bold;`, mainly because the font did not offer a bolded version. Why it decided to copy itself is beyond me.